# Qual a diferença entre freetexttable e containstable

Tags: sql-server

Estou montando uma query que precisará pegar o termo digitado numa pesquisa e fazer uma consulta por proximidade de semelhança no conteúdo. Está sendo utilizado um "rank" que é gerado com o uso desses comandos.

Os dois comandos me pareceram muito semelhantes, não consegui captar a diferença entre os dois. O que difere um do outro no SQL SERVER?

Comment: Veja:http://codingcanvas.com/full-text-queries-containstable-and-freetexttable-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O containstable permite especificar e construir com mais detalhes o que quer procurar (normalmente é mais útil quando tenho mais controlo no select que faço)
O freetexttable permite texto mais livre (daí o nome).
ex:

```
SELECT id, titulo FROM titulos
WHERE CONTAINS(notas, 'receita')

SELECT id, titulo FROM titulos
WHERE FREETEXT(notas, 'receita')
```

Ps: estou a usar o contais e o freetext para o exemplo ser mais simples
Estes dois selects podem dar resultados diferentes, porque o contains vai procurar apenas pela palavra receita, e o freetext vai procurar várias formas da palavra receita.

Comment: O que seriam essas várias formas da palavra receita?

Comment: Generates inflectional forms of the words (stemming). De uma forma simples: derivados da palavra (sinonimos, formas verbais, etc)